# Возврат результата по ссылке

Tags: php

```
function &returns_reference()
{
    return $someref;
}

$newref =& returns_reference();
```

Документация на php.net молчит, просто навела пример. Передача переменной внутрь функции через флаг &(Передача аргументов по ссылке) ясна, это совсем другое. Может кто-то расказать как для первокласника.

UPD : 
Нашел довольно интересный пример,который немного больше покажет истину

```
 $foo = 'foo';

    function & get_foo_ref () 
    { 
      global $foo; 
      return $foo; 
    }

    // Get the reference to variable $foo stored into $bar 
    $bar = & get_foo_ref(); 
    $bar = 'bar';

    echo $foo; // Outputs 'bar', since $bar references to $foo.
```

Comment: Непонятно что именно Вы хотите услышать. В официальном мане все отлично расписано. Ваш пример из update непосредственно вытекает из мана.  
Вообще же, когда я читал мануал, то не переставал удивляться- как же много в PHP способов писать извращенный код.  
Хотя это наверно потому, что не придумал адекватного применения возврату ссылок. Возможно, это очень нужная технология, просто я не сталкивался с задачами где бы это спасло/помогло/упростило.

Comment: та я уже вроде как разобрался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Возвращение по ссылке](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.return.php)

> Возвращение по ссылке используется в тех случаях, когда вы хотите использовать функцию для выбора переменной, с которой должна быть связана данная ссылка. Не используйте возврат по ссылке для увеличения производительности. Ядро PHP само занимается оптимизацией. Применяйте возврат по ссылке только имея технические причины на это.